# How do I Increase the Font Size of TextView in Android Studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, fonts, font-size

How do I increase the Font in textView on Android studio? I can set the font style but I can't find the attributes to increase the Font Size

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the attribute `fontSize` inside `TextStyle`.

Example:

```dart
Text(
   'Some text',
   style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20
   )
)
```

Doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html

Answer (score 0):

as you are working in XML try this `android:textSize="xsp"` replace that 'x' with the size you desire 'sp' scales the text if you want hardcoded text size try 'dp'